# Angular2 + RxJS BehaviorSubject subscription not working on all components

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to make some sort of communication between my components, so I'm using a service with a BehaviorSubject and Subscription in the components like this:

Service (code related to the problem):

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'

private _clientModalActionSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('')
modalAction$ = this._clientModalActionSource.asObservable()
public updateClientModalAction(action) {
   this._clientModalActionSource.next(action)
   console.log('sent')
}
```

Component A :

```
this._api.updateClientModalAction(id)
```

Component B :

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/subscription'

private _subscription: Subscription
ngOnInit() { this._subscription = this._api.modalAction$.subscribe(res => {
   this.refreshModal(res)
   console.log('received')
})}
```

This is working perfectly if Component B is child of Component A, but if A is the root component and B is inside its `<router-outlet>` (or the opposite) nothing is being received to the subscription, I only get `sent` in the console.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

well the problem was simpler than I thought, I was not using the service on a higher level, I shouldn't have used `providers: [ApiService]` in each component, instead it should be only on the higher root component.

I hope this will help someone.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11618#event-790191142

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day

Comment: Thanks a ton, bro !

Comment: Do we still need to do this if in the service its mentioned as @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) ? plz help!

Comment: It's strange, cause angular doesnt give any error so if i didnt read this question i couldnt found solution ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

if you are going to share things between components.

1. You should have to use that apiService in the high-level module. like :
   `providers: [ApiService]`.
2. You should have to be in the component to catch the subscription of rxjs in the component.

Answer (score 1):

besides of your answer you have to use

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'})
```

in order to load the service on the root.

Answer (score 0):

In my case subscription didn't happen because of a silent error in the inner function:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.infoService.entries.asObservable().subscribe(
      entries => {
        this.entryBody = entries[0].body;
      });
  }
```

As soon as I wrapped this line with a check it started to work:

```
if (entries.length > 0) {
  this.entryBody = entries[0].body;
}
```

So to clarify: there were no error messages in the console for failing array index.

Comment: It will fail if entries is undefined or null.
Check will be if (entries && entries.length > 0)